# How to use Enum to define values of string in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

let say I have Enum like bellow

```
export enum PERIOD {
  DAY = "DAILY",
  MONTH= "MONTHLY",
  YEAR= "YEARLY",
}
```

I have a variable that use `PERIOD` as interface

```
const period : keyof typeof PERIOD = "DAILY"
```

Typescript show error `Type '"DAILY"' is not assignable to type '"DAY " | "MONTH"| "YEAR"'`

How can I use value of enum as interface?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's possible. `keyof` will get the keys of the enum, I don't think there is a `valueof` operator.

The simplest way is to make the keys match the value.

```
enum PERIOD {
  DAILY = "DAILY",
  MONTHLY = "MONTHLY",
  YEARLY = "YEARLY",
}
```

Then the `keyof typeof PERIOD` will work.

Another option is to define the enum and an object that you can key into to get the value.

```
enum PERIOD {
  DAY,
  MONTH,
  YEAR,
}

export const periodMap: Record<PERIOD, string> = {
  [PERIOD.DAY]: 'DAILY',
  [PERIOD.MONTH]: 'MONTHLY',
  [PERIOD.YEAR]: 'YEARLY'
}

const period = periodMap[PERIOD.DAY]
```